# grabbing youtube video URL from curl or get_video_info

Tags: php, video, youtube

So, I am working on a php project and one part of it is grabbing a youtube video url and inserting it into an html5 video tag.  I was using a curl call to http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=XXX and getting the right video file urls on my local machine.

But, when I uploaded my code to my web server and tried to run it, none of the video URLs have worked.  The urls seemed fine but some parameters, like IP, where different.  I can't understand why it works from my local machine running xampp or mamp but not on my web server. I even tried just doing a curl on the youtube video page and noticed that locally, it would output the page and play the video but on my webserver, all the video calls got 404s.

Any info about this?  Anyway I can grab a youtube video url so that I can play youtube videos in a html5 video tag? Is this why keepvid and sites like that use the damn java applet?

Comment: Since you are getting 404, what URL was used?  Can you post some example code for fetching the info and matching data?

Comment: Isn´t YouTube not allowing you to do such things?

Comment: It is actually a 403, you can see it in this URL: http://o-o.preferred.iad09s12.v5.lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,source,ratebypass,cp&fexp=907911,914060,916201&itag=43&ip=208.0.0.0&signature=1810EA75ADD7E30581426A5262C030CF82348A98.5C2D5385C0DD8FCFCF46EF43BD7223C894825DB6&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&expire=1322629200&key=yt1&ipbits=8&cp=U0hRR1ZNV19FSkNOMV9OR0FDOlBIZnZ0Zl9jdXNF&id=1c8acc21e379b6d1&quality=medium&fallback_host=tc.v5.cache8.c.youtube.com&type=video/webm

Comment: If YouTube is not allowing it, then why does it work on my local machine and why do they have this request: http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=XXX

Comment: NB This is illegal, explicitly against the YT ToS

Answer (score 10):

You should take a look to [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/) project I'm pretty sure you can takes some idea to understand the proper way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Ok, I just checked it out and tested it and it works great but I wonder how they do it.  I don't know python, do they use get_video_info?

Comment: If you don't know python, I guess you know [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) or [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) ;)

Comment: Ok, using grep I see that they do use get_video_info and it is very similar to my php code.  In other words, the url they provide works locally but not on the server.  Since the file does download on the server, I assume that this is a problem with browser IP.  Locally my browser is the same as my local machine, but this is not the case when I use my browser to hit a page from my server.  So, the URL is correct for my server, that is why it works and downloads, but as the end user, that url is incorrect.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I've made a script in PHP to stream youtube videos to clinets recently and I think by alter a little bit of my script can fit your purpose.

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php 
@set_time_limit(0); //disable time limit to make sure the whole video is streamed to the client
$id = $_GET['id']; //the youtube video ID
$type = $_GET['type']; //the MIME type of the desired format

parse_str(file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id='.$id),$info); //get video info
$streams = explode(',',$info['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map']); //split the stream map into streams

foreach($streams as $stream){ 
    parse_str($stream,$real_stream); //parse the splitted stream
    $stype = $real_stream['type']; //the MIME type of the stream
    if(strpos($real_stream['type'],';') !== false){ //if a semicolon exists, that means the MIME type has a codec in it
        $tmp = explode(';',$real_stream['type']); //get rid of the codec
        $stype = $tmp[0]; 
        unset($tmp); 
    } 
    if($stype == $type && ($real_stream['quality'] == 'large' || $real_stream['quality'] == 'medium' || $real_stream['quality'] == 'small')){ //check whether the format is the desired format 
        header('Content-type: '.$stype); //send the HTTP headers
        header('Transfer-encoding: chunked'); //necessary for streaming
        @readfile($real_stream['url'].'&signature='.$real_stream['sig']); //send the content to the client
        ob_flush(); //disable PHP caching
        flush(); //flush the content out
        break; 
    } 
}
?>
```

I hope it can help you.

P.S. You need to send the content from the server because the video URL varies by ISPs.

Comment: It works but anyone have the similar code in pascal/delphi?

Answer (score 3):

The link that you extract only works for the IP address from which you extracted it. So, if you extract it from your local machine, it will work in the browser on your machine. However, if you extract it from your server, only the server will be able to access the video file from that link.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for download youtube video :

```
<?php
$id='5HDw7sQE2H0';
$dt=file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=$id&el=embedded&ps=default&eurl=&gl=US&hl=en");
$x=explode("&",$dt);
$t=array(); $g=array(); $h=array();
echo "<pre>\r\n";
foreach($x as $r){
    $c=explode("=",$r);
    $n=$c[0]; $v=$c[1];
    $y=urldecode($v);
    $t[$n]=$v;
}
$streams = explode(',',urldecode($t['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map']));
foreach($streams as $dt){ 
    $x=explode("&",$dt);
    foreach($x as $r){
        $c=explode("=",$r);
        $n=$c[0]; $v=$c[1];
        $h[$n]=urldecode($v);
    }
    $g[]=$h;
}
print_r($g);
echo "\r\n</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: you probably need to add the signature for it to work

Comment: On line 10, `$y` is never used. I think what you meant to write for line 11 was `$t[$n] = urldecode($v)`. Or rather, `$table[$name] = urldecode($value)`, cause who has a gun to your head, forcing you to use awful one-letter variable names?

Comment: I've used this kind of URL too but I can't get it to return a higher quality than 720p. Any idea to get 1080p?

Answer (score -2):

You can simply build an embed URL from the video ID

The big advantage here is that you can add your own parameters to the player as required.

For example an iframe src,

http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$video_id}?theme=light&autoplay=1&...