# Pass URL to PHP via $_GET

Tags: php

I've face weird problem below url when I copy and paste it into download manager, it works fine. But I am going to stream it in direct link via PHP then get an 400 error. However when I use the link into different upload center site (uploadboy.com) to test if the link works fine or not, it was working fine on the uploader.

I coded a script that I attach to affix. And try many different way to download it but still face error 400!

What action do I have taken to fix the problem?
I test to see if the script works urlencode and urldecode function on whole parts of url and on query string of url. in these 4 different ways no success to download. However I attached my script in one of the way I tested.

I notice you again. the link working fine and it's not limited to IP Address. However Download Manager that I test to download the url have same IP address with php webserver.

Sample of URL:

```
http://r5---sn-p5qlsnsk.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&mm=31&fexp=9407724,9408142,9408592,9408705,9408710,9408982,9412517,9412776,9413317,9413355,945137,948124,952612,952637,952640,952642&id=o-ACIY_VMiJqYl9lskpYea7F_6tP6DNv6WlJattCarpNST&signature=0DF7579F401F8BB481A4511F96ECD95C52FB618B.29AA2A450464D709E3FC3974759459A1EB7066E9&nh=IgpwcjAzLmlhZDA3KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&key=yt5&mt=1432113172&ip=198.50.235.216&upn=aR3Slhiml7g&expire=1432134981&sparams=dur,id,ip,ipbits,itag,mime,mm,ms,mv,nh,pl,source,upn,expire&mime=video/3gpp&sver=3&pl=23&source=youtube&mv=u&dur=87.817&itag=17&ms=au&signature= '&title='Youtube-API-V3-Drag--Drop-PlayList--Download-videos--Search-Keyword'
```

Sample of Code to stream:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$referrer = $_POST['referrer'];

if(strstr($url,'googlevideo.com')){
    $url_parts = parse_url($url);
    $query = $url_parts['query'];
    $query_parts = parse_str($query,$queries);

    foreach ($queries AS $key=>$value){
        $post_url .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
    }
    $post_url = rtrim($post_url, '&'); 

    $url2 = 'http://r1---sn-u2oxu-f5f6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?'.$post_url;

    die($url.'<br><br>'.$url2);
    $filename = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]/','', $title).'.'.getExtension($mime);


    // $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($url, TRUE));
    // $filesize = $head['content-length'];
    header('Pragma: public');   // required
    header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    // header('Content-Length: '.$filesize);    // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');

    // echo getUrl($url,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$referrer);

    $file = fopen(str_replace('&amp;','&',$url), 'rb');



    while (($content = fread($file, 20480)) !== false) { // Read in 2048-byte chunks
        echo $content; // or output it somehow else.
        flush(); // force output so far
    }
    fclose($file);
    exit();
}
```

**Update1:**
I already test below curl function:

```
function getUrl($url,$agent='',$referrer='',$proxy=''){
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    if(!empty($agent)){
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$agent);
    }
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    if(!empty($referrer)){
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referrer); 
    }
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,false);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Trying to download YouTube video ? :-)

Comment: Yes, I achieved to generate download link but I can not download it via php. :( Some of users complaining about googlevideo.com is blocked in their country.

Comment: have you tried using curl? I don't know if it is legal to download stuff from you tube. you should check it before doing such things.

Comment: Yes, I already tried it. Well it's a proxy service to give a chance to Iranian people watch YouTube videos. they suffer high internet censorship.

Comment: I would definitely recommend CURL for this use case.

Comment: I already test it via curl please note the new update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 400 error comes from a typo in your url: remove the space character in this part: `&signature= '&title='`.

Your curl function is ok, but it doesn't work with your url. I don't know why not, but it works with an url like this: `https://youtu.be/LxBk5f6mr-A`.

Perhaps you can use the tool mentioned in this post:

[grabbing youtube video URL from curl or get_video_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317199/grabbing-youtube-video-url-from-curl-or-get-video-info)