# Get direct url of youtube video

Tags: youtube

I wonder how to get the direct url of youtube video. For example, when i analyzed the video code of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrTyD7rjBpw

i found some URLs inside the js code of the player, like https://r6---sn-w511uxa-cjoe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mt=1440164084&mv=m&ms=au&mm=31&mn=sn-w511uxa-cjoe&upn=ELDhWOVFRzM&id=o-AM6zxCNJwi5l5gjbq_262NpEnieXQ2iQTkGLLDieVKs4&ip=188.77.186.165&sparams=dur%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&fexp=3300113%2C3300134%2C3300137%2C3300164%2C3310699%2C3312381%2C3312531%2C9407535%2C9408710%2C9409069%2C9412877%2C9413010%2C9414935%2C9415365%2C9415417%2C9415485%2C9416023%2C9416105%2C9416126%2C9416522%2C9417353%2C9417707%2C9418060%2C9418153%2C9418203%2C9418449%2C9419675&dur=0.000&initcwndbps=1298750&pl=20&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&gcr=es&pcm2cms=yes&requiressl=yes&expire=1440185744&mime=video%2Fwebm&key=yt5&ipbits=0&lmt=1365511426344921&sver=3&itag=43

But it doesn't redirect to the youtube video, so i'm thinking that code is more obfuscated

Comment: Would the embed link work, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/embed/OrTyD7rjBpw ?

Comment: need the video url for a php script

Comment: Your question is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php

Comment: i don't want the embed code, i want the direct url to the video

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grabbing youtube video URL from curl or get\_video\_info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317199/grabbing-youtube-video-url-from-curl-or-get-video-info)

Answer (score 3):

There's a library for that, and a linux tool, called `youtube-dl` and `libquvi`, respectively, which support URL extraction from player pages. You can call `youtube-dl -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrTyD7rjBpw` to get a URL pointing to the video.

Note that many CDNs won't give you a redistributable URL for a video -- instead, it's a URL that will only work for whoever requested the video.

Also note: there's not "one" video stream at a youtube page, but several ones, for different qualities and devices.

Comment: do you know if there's a youtube-dl library for php without using the sh script?